# Initializing a variable inside of an if-statement in C?

Tags: c, recursion, depth-first-search, maze

I am not sure what is wrong with how I am initializing the variables `count` and `invFlag`. Are you not allowed to initialize variables inside of an if statement? In case you are wondering this is a portion of my code to check if the maze I solved recursively is correct (i.e. checking if there is a path given by '.' that takes me from the start 'S' to the end 'E'). The maze is being solved correctly in the function solveMaze but this function is simply to check and see if it was solved correctly. I use the variable invFlag to make sure for example that I don't go down and then the next call up because that would be pointless). At the beginning (when I am at the start 'S', I want to initialize this invFlag to a junk value as I did). This is a portion of the code.

I am receiving this error:

```
maze.c: In function ‘checkMaze’:
maze.c:151: error: ‘count’ undeclared (first use in this function)
maze.c:151: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
maze.c:151: error: for each function it appears in.)
maze.c:152: error: ‘invFlag’ undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [maze.o] Error 1
```

A portion of my code:

```c
int checkMaze(char ** maze, int width, int height, int x, int y)

if(maze[y][x] == 'S')
{
    int invFlag, count;
    invFlag = 4;     // junk value
    count = 0;
}

if(count <=15)
        printf("y: %d  x:  %d invFlag: %d \n", y, x, invFlag);

count = count+1;

if (maze[y][x] == 'E')
    return 1;

/* recursive calls (order: right, up, left, down) */

// if right of current position is '.' move there
if ( ( (maze[y][x+1] == '.') || (maze[y][x+1]  == 'E') ) && (invFlag != 2 ) ) 
{   
    invFlag = 0;    // right move will be performed
    checkMaze(maze, width, height, x + 1, y);
}

// if up of current position is '.' move there
else if ( (maze[y-1][x] == '.' || maze[y-1][x]  == 'E') && ( invFlag != 3) )
{
    invFlag = 1;    // up move will be performed
    checkMaze(maze, width, height, x, y - 1);
}

// if left of current position is '.' move there
else if ( (maze[y][x-1] == '.' || maze[y][x-1]  == 'E') && (invFlag != 0 ))
{   
    invFlag = 2;    // left move will be performed
    checkMaze(maze, width, height, x - 1, y);
}

// if down of current position is '.' move there
else if ( (maze[y+1][x] == '.' || maze[y+1][x]  == 'E') && (invFlag != 1 ))
{
    invFlag = 3;    // down move will be performed
    checkMaze(maze, width, height, x, y + 1);
}

return 0;  // maze solution was not correct
}
```

Comment: The variable will not be declared in the second `if`. So what are you trying to do?

Comment: The second `if` was just for debugging purposes. Don't believe it really applies.

Comment: It sounds like you have a fundamental design error: the object you are trying to refer to via `invFlag` is not a local to an individal call to `checkMaze`, so declaring it as a local variable does the wrong thing. It (or maybe a pointer to it) needs to be an *argument* to `checkMaze`, or something similar.

Comment: @Hurkyl , yes, having it as an argument to the function is the most logical thing to do and simplest but the main function is already created in the assignment and we are not allowed to modify it simply write the code for the function with the given arguments.

Comment: @user: Then write a helper function that has the correct arguments and does all the work, and have `checkMaze` simply declare and initialize the objects you need then call your helper function. That's probably what you should do even without the constraint of your assignment, if you go with this approach to implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The visibility of the variable count is just within the `if()` block

```
if()
{
  //count is visible within if
}

// count is unknown here
```

Since count is not known outside of the if() block compiler is reporting error this can be fixed by moving the variable declaration outside of the if() block like

```
int count;

if()
{
  // count is visible
}
// count is visible
```

Comment: I understand now. I was just concerned that since I am calling checkMaze(...) recursively, re-declaration would be a problem since I want it to keep the value of invFlag.

Comment: If you want to retain the value of a variable across function calls you can make it `static` but I have just explained why you see error with the code which you have posted

Answer (score 2):

The initialization is not the problem, you are **declaring** them inside the `if` block, so they are not declared at the function scope, hence the error.

Just move this

```
int invFlag, count;
```

outside of the `if` block to the function scope, and then it will compile, whether it will work is another thing, it's a bad idea to leave the variable uninitialized unless you are certain that there will not be any access that precedes initialization.

It seems that you are working with `gcc` which would warn about that if you invoke it with `-Wall`.

If there is another declaration of `invFlag` then the `invFlag` outside the `if` block is not the `invFlag` that you declared in the `if` block, in that case just remove the declaration, and use `-Wshadow` to make **gcc** warn about that.

Comment: Ok, I guess that was my question. So I am not allowed to declare them inside of an if? How should I go about this since I only want to set `invFlag` to junk value for the starting position in the maze 'S'. After that, each if for left,right, down, up moves will take care of setting the correct `invFlag` value.

Comment: You are allowed to do it, but you can't access them outside of the `if` block.

Comment: Gotcha. But is it a problem that they would be re-declared at each recursive call? Is that ever a problem in C?

Comment: It's not, it depends on what you need to do, you can redeclared it like this for example `while (1) {int x = 0; ... }` and it's ok, but it depends on your use case, I am guessing that you did not post the actual code, so you make me give an answer based on assumptions.